# Android onPictureTaken to Intent

Tags: java, android, camera

My objective is to have a custom camera, with a snap button (imgSnap), when this is pressed I want the app to go to another intent (CameraReview) where the image is shown in an imageview, here the user can select keep or delete. the code bellow works until I start the review intent, there it just pauses on the camera preview and breaks. I am unable to find the reason why this is.

```
Button imgSnap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgSnap);
            imgSnap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Taken",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(x, CameraReview.class);
                            intent.putExtra("image_arr", data);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            webView.startActivity(intent);
                            camera.stopPreview();
                            if (camera != null) {
                                camera.release();
                                mCamera = null;
                            }
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Edit:
The following exception is thrown:

```
Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called
```

Comment: You would need to provide the complete stack trace. Beyond that, your approach will fail if `data` is close to or over 1MB, as you cannot pass large blocks of data via `Intent` extras. I recommend that you keep this all within one activity, perhaps using fragments or something to switch between different UI modes (camera preview vs. review).

Comment: I think you are right, I changed the extra to a string which is smaller in size and the application no longer crashes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are having two different Camera instance. one of them is looking unrelated with your code.

Try changing

```
     camera.stopPreview(); 
     if (camera != null) { 
     camera.release(); 
     mCamera = null; 
     }
```

To

```
 mCamera.stopPreview(); 
 if (mCamera != null) { 
 mCamera.release(); 
 mCamera = null; 
 }
```